# Fuelphp routing

Tags: php, routes, fuelphp

I ve just installed last 1.7 version of Fuelphp and trying to play without routes, but got stuck a bit

What was done:

Created "special" action in "userspace" controller

```
public function action_special($a = 'empty')
{
    var_dump($a);
    die();
}
```

And routing for it

```
'test(/:any)?' => 'userspace/special/$1'
```

But the problem is if **localhost/test** returns

```
string(5) "empty"
```

so **localhost/test/1** or **localhost/test/qwerty** returns

```
string(0) ""
```

but full path **localhost/userspace/special/qwerty** returns

```
string(6) "qwerty"
```

So somehow our "special" method cant get a parameter from routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we're using regular expressions, routes are powerful but sometimes confusing. The regex should be something like:

```
'something(/(:any))?' => 'something/index/$2',
```

The (groups) are captured, but :any by itself is not captured, you'll need an extra (group) like the example above. And because it's the second group we'll put `$2` in the route translation.

Comment: Your example is working perfectly, but why in official documentation (http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/routing.html) there is examples like    
**'blog/(:any)'**      => **'blog/entry/$1'**

Comment: Because you want the optional `/` you need 2 groups, in my example there are two, in the docs there is one group, so that is correct. Can you accept my answer? :)

Comment: Ofcourse i just wanted to get right up to the end, thank you alot :)